# Best location to put your CSS and JS files in a Mavenized Java Web app?

Tags: java, javascript, css, maven-2, war

I have a Web application in maven that follows this structure:

```
src
`-- main
    |-- java
    |-- resources
    `-- webapp
```

Is is better to put it in the main folder and then the maven plug in will try to move it or I should put it inside the webapp folder and why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't need to filter CSS and JS files, I would simply put them in `src/main/webapp` (if you put them in `src/main/resources`, they will end up in `target/classes` and in `WEB-INF/classes` in the WAR which is very unlikely what you want). If you need to filter them, additional resources can be included in the WAR using the `webResources` parameter. Have a look at [Adding and Filtering External Web Resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that explained why I see both flavors when goggling the location

Answer (score 6):

I think they should be under `src\main\webapp`.  The main rationale for saying this is that this is the standard [suggested](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) by Maven, and the Maven philosophy is that all projects should follow the same structure as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

*"If there are other contributing sources to the artifact build, they would be under other subdirectories: for example `src/main/antlr` would contain Antlr grammar definition files."*

So I think `src/main/javascript` and `src/main/css` is the right place...

What do you think?

Comment: Very much inclined to agree with you. JavaScript and CSS are separate languages with their own nuances and use cases, not simply add ons or managed scripts bundled along java (as much as I love java!)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing quite a variation of answers to this question.  One set of threads (like some people in this thread) seem to think that Maven apps should place css/images/js files into the src\main\webapp  folder - similar to the traditional J2EE pattern.  Others feel that the
resources (or another similar peer) folder outside of webapps should be used instead:

[What are the conventional locations for for JSPs, JavaScript, CSS, Images in Maven web projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542382/maven-web-project-source-locations-for-jsps-javascript-css-images)

I have yet to form an opinion, but it would seem to make sense to separate these client side types of files from the server side - if only because in high performance focused production situations, the static client side files such as these are typically separated out and placed into a cacheable front end web server for faster access anyway, so keeping them in their own separate resources folder would seem to make this job easier.