# How to make HTML read CSS in a Maven project

Tags: java, html, css, maven

I created a Maven Project in STS, with no archetype and having packaging as "war".

The project structure is as follow

```
portal
    ----Deployment Descriptor: portal
    ----JAX-WS Web Services
    ----Java Resources
        ----src
            ----main
                ----java
                ----resources
                    ----assets
                        ----login.css
                ----webapp
                    ----login.html
            ----test
                ----java
                ----resources
        ----Libraries
    ----Javascript Resources
    ----Deployed Resources
    ----target          
    ----pom.xml
```

I created `login.html` in `src/main/webapp` folder and created `assets/login.css` in `src/main/resources`.

My question is that when I try to include that css file in the html code, it is unable to read that.

What to do for that?

Also, after googling a bit, I came to know that for such situations, put the files in WEB-INF and it'll do all the rest. But while creating the project, WEB-INF folder was not created. Although I can create it myself, but just want to know where I am doing wrong in creating a maven project which should by default create WEB-INF folder.

Comment: What web server are you running ?
The HTML doesn't read anything, it is only interpreted and the browser makes extra requests for any resource it requires. Have you checked browser console ? Does it throw any errors ?

Comment: You (for the basic use case) cannot put CSS files into WEB-INF, since anything that's in WEB-INF is not accessible directly through an URL.

Comment: When you build the `war`, in what path does the `css` file end up? I'd expect `resources` to be put into `web-inf`, while you want the css file to be in public part. `webapp` should be the right place in my understanding.

Comment: @Catalin I am using Tomcat v7.0.

Comment: @Catalin It says "Failed to load resource"

Comment: Okay, then either assets folder is not public (I can't tell for sure) or you're using the wrong path in your html. You could try moving your web resources in webapp and then see if it works.

Comment: @Catalin It works through that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information you provided, I can guess you created a new maven project as **[x]Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)**. If you did create the project this way it will not create a WEB-INF folder by default.

If you do *New->Maven Project->Next-> and select* a maven-archetype-**webapp** by default you will end up with a WEB-INF folder. *NOTICE:* the **"webapp"** archetype.

And regarding where to put the .css files. Maven's Standard Directory Layout suggest `src/main/webapp` for Web application resources.
This other [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542382/what-are-the-conventional-locations-for-for-jsps-javascript-css-images-in-mav) has a good answer for where to .css files for web projects.