# Where to place static client side files in maven project

Tags: java, maven

I created a new simple maven project. I was following the project structure found [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html), however, it doesn't state where to place `.js, .sql, .html, .css, .jsp` files. Where do I place static client side files such as these in my maven project?

---

Here is the project structure that I have now:

[image]

---

EDIT:

Also, this question is different from the one posted as a duplicated since my question involves general static files whereas the other question involves specific files like javascript. Please reopen.

Comment: I thought such things went into the webapp directory as appropriate.

Comment: @KevinO That is where I have it now i.e under webapp. However, not sure of the naming conventions for the static files. If it does indeed need to be under webapp, do I create additional folders named html, javascript, css, etc?

Comment: Well, we have `index.jsp` directly under `src/main/webapp`. There are directories for `css`, and `.css` files are there (and properly referenced in the includes). Part of the structure depends upon other things -- such as do you use a filter for 'secure' pages and have them under `/secure/SOMEPAGE.jsp`?

Comment: @KevinO Nope, nothing like secure. It is a very basic project

Comment: Well, nonetheless, separating some things, like .css is a good practice, so those can go in a `css` subdirectory. EDIT: also things like the web.xml go in the webapp directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the conventional locations for for JSPs, JavaScript, CSS, Images in Maven web projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542382/what-are-the-conventional-locations-for-for-jsps-javascript-css-images-in-mav)

Comment: @MichaelPeacock Similar question but it's not a duplicate. Also, that question is six years old.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using WAR packaging, in `webapp`. If you are using JAR packaging, in `resources`.

**EDIT:** the `.sql` files should go always in `resources`

Comment: But what will be the folder name under webapp?

Comment: the folder structure is free. However the index.html or index.jsp should go in `webapp/index.html` or `webapp/index.jsp`